# CakePHP and multiselect checkbox

Tags: arrays, input, checkbox, selected

I'm sorry I've looked everywhere. For sure I'm doing a basic error in PHP using arrays. FormHelper returns me the correct HTML input checkbox only when I use the parameter 'selected' => array (1,45,46). When they try to use the array sent from the controller does not display properly. How to convert an array to work in a parameter 'selected'. What am I doing wrong.

```
    debug($selected_dostrony);
/*
array(
    (int) 0 => '1',
    (int) 1 => '45',
    (int) 2 => '39',
    (int) 3 => '46',
    (int) 4 => '40',
    (int) 5 => '41',
    (int) 6 => '42',
    (int) 7 => '43',
    (int) 8 => '44'
)
*/



$selected_dostrony=implode(", ", $selected_dopostu);
debug($selected_dostrony);

/*
'1, 45, 39, 46, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44'
```

*/

```
echo $this->Form->input('Product', array('multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $dopostu, 'selected' => $selected_dopostu));
echo $this->Form->input('Product', array('multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $dopostu, 'selected' => $selected_dostrony));

/* this works */
    echo $this->Form->input('Product', array('multiple' => 'checkbox', 'options' => $dopostu, 'selected' => array(1,45,46)));
```

Comment: always use integer **intval($product[0]['Post']['id'])**